# Query on Scopus: restrict the search of field to journals only

Tags: label, journal, scopus

I have a quite simple problem.

I want to make a query on Scopus and I know that to restrict the search of field to title, abstract e keywords I could use the label "TITLE-ABS-KEY" at the beginning of my query.

My question is: how could I restrict the search of field to the different journal categories?

Example. I need all the journal correlated with "MARKETING"

I expected a query like (for example) : JOURNAL("Marketing")

Which is the label that I have to use to substitute "JOURNAL"?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

According to Scopus Seearch Tips documentation, in the query must be added the parameter "SUBJAREA", for example:

> http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=SUBJAREA(CHEM)&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

This query search all articles related with CHEMISTRY.

In [this link](https://dev.elsevier.com/tips/ScopusSearchTips.htm) are all the available options for **SUBJAREA(XX)**.

I hope I've helped :)